# Keil memory window

Tags: memory, cortex-m, keil

I need to write data to the program’s internal memory (flash) at an address starting at 0x08000000 for further processing. To do this, I open the memory window with the desired address, select the byte, enter the number, press "Enter", but nothing happens and the data entered is not saved. You can watch the video demonstrating the process here: https://2ch.hk/pr/src/1499956/15818644469750.mp4. In this case, the data at 0x20000000 is recorded without problems. But I need the data exactly in the flash, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger is not capable of writing to flash.  You can get your data into that memory location in one of two ways: either by embedding it into your source code and using the linker to control its location, or by writing to the flash from software (assuming the device you're using is able to do this, most are - check the device manual).